# postgresql посмотреть какие внешние ключи ссылаются на таблицу

Tags: postgresql

В oracle all_constraints можно по r_constraint_name можно сделать запрос, чтобы он выводил от каких таблиц зависит нужная таблица
А в postgesql information_schema.table_constraints, pg_catalog.pg_constraint и других такой инфы нет

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Команда `\d tablename` в `psql` покажет и FK с этой таблицы на другие, и, отдельно, FK с других таблиц на эту.

А раз psql это умеет показывать - значит, как любой клиент, это может откуда-то прочитать из ббазы. Если запустить `psql -E` то можно увидеть производимые запросы. В частности (на моей 13 версии для таблички с `oid=418144`):

```
SELECT true as sametable, conname,
  pg_catalog.pg_get_constraintdef(r.oid, true) as condef,
  conrelid::pg_catalog.regclass AS ontable
FROM pg_catalog.pg_constraint r
WHERE r.conrelid = '418144' AND r.contype = 'f'
     AND conparentid = 0
ORDER BY conname
```

FK на этой таблице.

```
SELECT conname, conrelid::pg_catalog.regclass AS ontable,
       pg_catalog.pg_get_constraintdef(oid, true) AS condef
  FROM pg_catalog.pg_constraint c
 WHERE confrelid IN (SELECT pg_catalog.pg_partition_ancestors('418144')
                     UNION ALL VALUES ('418144'::pg_catalog.regclass))
       AND contype = 'f' AND conparentid = 0
ORDER BY conname;
```

FK ссылающиеся на эту таблицу.

Числовой OID можно без потери смысла запроса заменить на `your_tablename::pg_catalog.regclass`, тогда СУБД самостоятельно преобразует в OID.

> А в postgresql information_schema.table_constraints, pg_catalog.pg_constraint и других такой инфы нет

Вы не правы: [`pg_constraint.confrelid`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-constraint.html) относится именно к FK.

А в определённой стандартом `information_schema` внешние ключи показывает не `table_constraints`, а специальная [`referential_constraints`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/infoschema-referential-constraints.html). Из которой можно вытащить `unique_constraint_name` - имя уникального ограничения или первичного ключа, по которому уже найти таблицу, на которую ссылается этот FK.